# Using filters with gridview and stored procedures in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, filter

I have a gridview that's populated by a stored procedure. On this dataset, the user should be able to filter it by selecting the LabID and/or SiteName from 2 dropdownlists. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLabIDs" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="LabID" 
        DataValueField="LabID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="exec usp_LabIDs_Select;"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSiteNames" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="SiteName" 
        DataValueField="SiteName" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="exec usp_SiteNames_Select;"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="AllDataFlat" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20"
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LabID" HeaderText="LabID" SortExpression="LabID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteName" HeaderText="SiteName" 
                SortExpression="SiteName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDateTime" HeaderText="StartDateTime" 
                SortExpression="StartDateTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FilterNumber" HeaderText="FilterNumber" 
                SortExpression="FilterNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AmtWaterFiltered" HeaderText="AmtWaterFiltered" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AmtWaterFiltered" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WaterTemp" HeaderText="WaterTemp" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="WaterTemp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="pH" HeaderText="pH" SortExpression="pH" />                
        </Columns>           
    </asp:GridView>        

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="exec usp_AllDataFlat_Select;">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry ,if i am unclear , what you want .....?????

Comment: I want to be able to filter the datagrid using the LabID and SiteName dropdownlists.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.....

NOTE : this is just example on how to filter the grid view with the selected values on  two drop down lists...

```
<%@ page autoeventwireup="true" codefile="FilterWithMultipleDropDownLists.aspx.cs"
        inherits="GridView_FilterWithMultipleDropDownLists" language="C#" masterpagefile="~/MasterPages/Default.master"
        title="GridView: Filter With Multiple DropDownLists" %>

<asp:content id="Content1" runat="Server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">
        <div>
                Select Supplier:
                <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlSuppliers" runat="server" appenddatabounditems="True" autopostback="True"
                        datasourceid="sdsSuppliers" datatextfield="CompanyName" datavaluefield="SupplierID">
                        <asp:listitem text="All Suppliers" value="-1">
                        </asp:listitem>
                </asp:dropdownlist>
                <asp:sqldatasource id="sdsSuppliers" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
                        selectcommand="SELECT [SupplierID], [CompanyName] FROM [Suppliers] ORDER BY [CompanyName]">
                </asp:sqldatasource>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 12px;">
                Select Category:
                <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlCategories" runat="server" appenddatabounditems="True" autopostback="True"
                        datasourceid="sdsCategories" datatextfield="CategoryName" datavaluefield="CategoryID">
                        <asp:listitem text="All Categories" value="-1">
                        </asp:listitem>
                </asp:dropdownlist>
                <asp:sqldatasource id="sdsCategories" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
                        selectcommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName] FROM [Categories] ORDER By [CategoryName]">
                </asp:sqldatasource>
        </div>
        <asp:gridview id="gvProducts" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" datakeynames="ProductID"
                datasourceid="sdsProducts" style="margin-top: 24px;">
                <columns>
                        <asp:boundfield datafield="ProductID" headertext="ProductID" insertvisible="False"
                                readonly="True" sortexpression="ProductID" />
                        <asp:boundfield datafield="ProductName" headertext="ProductName" sortexpression="ProductName" />
                        <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Supplier" sortexpression="CompanyName" />
                        <asp:boundfield datafield="CategoryName" headertext="Category" sortexpression="CategoryName" />
                </columns>
        </asp:gridview>
        <asp:sqldatasource id="sdsProducts" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
                selectcommand="SELECT [P].[ProductID], [P].[ProductName], [P].[SupplierID], [P].[CategoryID], [S].[CompanyName], [C].[CategoryName] FROM [Products] AS [P] INNER JOIN [Suppliers] AS [S] ON [S].[SupplierID] = [P].[SupplierID] INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [C] ON [C].[CategoryID] = [P].[CategoryID] WHERE ([P].[SupplierID] = CASE WHEN @SupplierID = -1 THEN [P].[SupplierID] ELSE @SupplierID END AND [P].[CategoryID] = CASE WHEN @CategoryID = -1 THEN [P].[CategoryID] ELSE @CategoryID END) ORDER BY [P].[ProductName]">
                <selectparameters>
                        <asp:controlparameter controlid="ddlSuppliers" name="SupplierID" propertyname="SelectedValue" type="Int32" />
                        <asp:controlparameter controlid="ddlCategories" name="CategoryID" propertyname="SelectedValue" type="Int32" />
                </selectparameters>
        </asp:sqldatasource>
</asp:content>
```

I hope it will helps you..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm trying to do this using stored procedures. It's what I'm given.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this would be to pass the values selected in the drop down controls to the stored procedure usp_AllDataFlat_Select. In this stored procedure you should be able to select only the rows that satisfy the filter values.

If you do not have access to the stored procedures (can't modify them) than in my oppinion the best way to achieve this is to wrap your call to the stored procedure in an object that retrieves all the rows from the data base and filters them in memory (not very efficient). Then you can use an OnjectDataSource instead of the SqlDataSource to populate the gridview. This ObjectDataSoruce could call the methods of the object that wraps your stored procedures.

You can find an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridviewObjectDataSrc.aspx). The example uses queries instead of stored procedures but replacing the queries with calls to stored procedures should be trivial.

Best of luck,